# Reading active/inactive status of Startup programs in registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

In the software I'm currently working on, we encountered a scenario where we need to tell if a software is listed as a Startup program or not.

To tell if this program is enabled or not by the msconfig tool, I used the answer suggested by [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/664641/where-are-disabled-autostart-programs-stored-somewhere-in-the-registry).

However, not all softwares use the binary value "02 00 00 00..." when enabled, we encountered one that has the value "06 00 00 00...".

To understand it further I analyzed both scenarios by reading the softwares' registry values before disabling them and then afterwards:

- The expected scenario changed from `02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` to `03 00 00 00 17 79 BD 01 17 D9 D1 01`;
- The unexpected scenario changed from `06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` to `07 00 00 00 71 C9 33 AE 16 D9 D1 01`

I'm inclined to assume that the first byte contains the correct answer. In both cases the bit 1 changed from 0 to 1. It seems that this bit contains the active/inactive value. But I'm still not quite sure.

So my question is: Can I assume that this bit contain the correct value, or does anyone have a better answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems based on your example that you just need to set the 0th bit (zero based) of the first byte. So, in essence, just add 1 to the first hex byte (or right most nibble, if that makes it easier to think about) to disable (i.e., deactivate the app during startup).

So if the first byte is: X0, X2, X4, or X6, it becomes X1, X3, X5, or X7, respectively, where X is a don't care.

Comment: Actually it's the first bit. One change from 02 to 03, and the other from 06 to 07.

Comment: I updated my answer, now that I better understand your question

Comment: I'll run some tests before assuming this is correct